# My concateneate in groovy dont work

Tags: testing, groovy, tdd, soapui

I have a question, how i can concatenate my way with my file

```
import java.util.Properties
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def path = groovyUtils.projectPath

Properties properties = new Properties();
File propertiesFile = (path + JsonConfig.properties);
log.info propertiesFile
propertiesFile.withInputStream {
   stream -> properties.load(stream);
}

iterator = properties.keySet().iterator();

while(iterator.hasNext()) {
       key = iterator.next();
       value = properties[key];

       testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue(key, value);
}
```

The error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'E:\JsonConfig.properties' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.io.File' error at line: 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`path + JsonConfig.properties` appears to be a `String`.  You might want to call the `File` constructor.  Replace:

```
File propertiesFile = (path + JsonConfig.properties);
```

with:

```
File propertiesFile = new File(path + JsonConfig.properties);
```